# ARKit: How to add button to ARView in storyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am brand new to ARKit (and a novice in swift) but I am trying to create a basic AR app. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bGa4bhOHeY) in which a simple scene is created essentially doing everything in reality composer apart from the addition of a simple start scene button which is added to the ARView in the storyboard - you can see that specific moment in the tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/2bGa4bhOHeY?t=1159). When I attempt to do the same however, the `button` element replaces the `ARView` entirely, rather than it being added as a child of the ARView as happens in this tutorial.

You can see below a grab of what is going on. Here is the storyboard before I add the button.

[image: Storyboard before adding button]

I then search for a button element, drag onto ARView, at which point it replaces it, rather than adding as child. See below the result.

[image: Storyboard after adding button]

My xcode version is 11.2.

Any advice is much appreciated, and if any more info is needed, please ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must nest both the `ARView` and Button under a `UIView`. First, add a `UIView` as a direct child to the `ViewController`. Then, add an `ARView` under the `UIView` that you created before. Then, you can also add a `UIButton` under that same UIView.

Edit: After Viewing the tutorial video linked in your question, the "ARView" the tutorial has as the child of the `ViewController` is not an actual `ARView` but a `UIView` renamed to "ARView", to clarify.

Comment: Hi, thank you. If I could follow up, the hierarchy of elements has been created automatically when I start an `augmented reality app project` I have not edited the code or storyboard beyond what is provided by default. Am I able to do what you suggest through the storyboard? Or do I need to do this in code in `ViewController.swift`. If I drag a UIView element onto the storyboard it does, the same, replacing the `AR View` element in my hierarchy and then the app just displays a white screen.. Conscious I am asking basic questions but I thought what I was trying to achieve was simple

Comment: @Nick Yes, no code is needed. First you replace your existing ARView ith a UIView. Then you add another UIView as a child to the UIView you just created if you want. Then you add a button as a child to the same existing UIView. Also, you must have a different version of XCode than me, because I do not get this layout when I choose "AR app" to start. Hope this helps! Also, In the tutorial, the "AR View" you see the tutorial has is actually a UIView renamed to an ARView. Sorry it took me so long to respond, I was away from my computer.

Comment: @Nick I'm sorry, I meant add an ARView as a child to the UIView if you want, not add a UIView as a child! My bad, didn't catch this until later. Sorry if I'm explaining this in a confusing way, there's just a lot of steps but it's simple.

Comment: Hi - no problem at all - thank you, that works! So this is essentially 2 views on top of one another, one handling AR and the other handling UI, makes sense. I still don't completely understand what has changed though, as prior to a recent update I was able to add buttons to the default ARView (or thats what I thought was going on) That youtube video also seems to suggest that is possible it seems as though they have a type of view which is both Ar View and UIView enabled - otherwise how are they able to have both the AR working, and a button within the same element? anyway, thank you

Answer (score 3):

### Manually

- in `main.storyboard`, delete current ARView
- add UIView to empty controller
- add new ARView
- activate layout constraints
- add buttons (and other views)

### Programmatically

The easiest way to add buttons to RealityKit's `ARView` is to add them programmatically. Using this approach, you do not need to delete the current `ARView`. If you want to programmatically activate `NSLayoutConstraints`, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168059/unable-to-activate-constraint-with-anchors/72129589#72129589).

Here's a code.

```
import RealityKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()           
        let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
        
        let rect1 = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 50)
        let rect2 = CGRect(x: 120, y: 50, width: 100, height: 50)
        
        // PLAY BUTTON
        let playButton = UIButton(frame: rect1)
        playButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        playButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(play), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        // STOP BUTTON
        let stopButton = UIButton(frame: rect2)
        stopButton.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
        stopButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stop), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(playButton)
        self.view.addSubview(stopButton)
        
        self.loadAudio()
    }       
    @objc func play(sender: UIButton!) {
        self.audioController?.play()
    }
    @objc func stop(sender: UIButton!) {
        self.audioController?.pause()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Joey's correct. For some reason Apple's AR Template does not include a UIView, and you end with what Nick describes. Here is the step by step process so you can get use Interface Builder with RealityKit:

- Create a New Project
- Select Augmented Reality App
- Enter Product Name. Select RealityKit for Content Technology, and Storyboard for User Interface.
- Select Main.storyboard.
- Press '+' and add a UIVIew over the ARVIew
- Now press '+' again to drag a RealityKit AR View
- Connect the new ARView to the arView outlet in the View Controller.
- Now you can add UI elements as well without the AR View being replaced.